# There is no javax.servlet package in my JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, environment-variables

I am following `Head First: Servlet and JSP` and I was writing my first Servlet.
I tried to compile it using command line and I got an error that `package javax.servlet` does not exist.

So far, I have set the `JAVA_HOME` variable to the value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11` 
and the `PATH`  variable also to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin`

**How do I get the `javax.servlet` package?**

Also, I have installed `JDK 7 update 11` after the applet bug that was being exploited.
I have both `JDK Update 11` and `JDK Update 9` installed.
Should I get rid of `Update 9` or is it not needed ?

### Misc

**Operating System:** Windows 7 Home Premium 32 bit

*What I also tried:*

`javac -cp .;D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\lib\servlet-api.jar Ch1servlet.java`

I tried both forward slash AND backward slash. In both the cases I got an invalid flag error.

Comment: See absolutely great answer by BalusC here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4076706/1360074

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
javac -cp .;D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\lib\servlet-api.jar Ch1servlet.java
```

You're 99% of the way there, you just need to put some extra quotes in because the path to your servlet API jar contains spaces. Try this:

```
javac -cp ".;D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\lib\servlet-api.jar" Ch1servlet.java
```

Comment: Worked!! Can I set any environment variable to do this automatically ? So that I will not have to type  the verbose path again and again? :)

Comment: `set $CLASSPATH=%CLASSAPTH%;D:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.35-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\lib\servlet-api.jar;`

Comment: @LittleChild I wouldn't recommend using the command line `javac` directly for anything but the simplest one off compiles. At the very least you should write a `.bat` file or similar to call the compiler with the right options, but better would be to learn how to use a proper build tool such as Ant and/or an IDE such as Eclipse to handle the complexity for you.

Comment: @IanRoberts I will heed BalusC's advise and learn the servlets hard way first. This was just the beginning. I have 2000 pages ahead of me! I hope they will explain later what you are saying. **What about the JDK thing?**

Comment: @LittleChild as a professional developer of client side software I find it handy to keep a few different versions of the JDK so that when I receive a bug report I can reproduce it on the same version that the client is using.  But if you're just doing server-side development and you control the server's JDK version then that's not so necessary.

Answer (score 2):

It will not be because

- Servlets are part of Java-EE and not Java-SE
- You need to download and add java-ee libraries if you need to use servlets

Comment: you need other `.jar` like j2ee.jar javaee.jar